# pyodbc Cursor.Execute freezes when using prepared statements

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, pyodbc

I am using Python 2.7 and pyodbc to talk to a Postgresql database. The execute statement freezes and does not return when I use prepared statement. If I use straight sql then it works fine. Any ideas?

Here is what I have in code:

```
DBconn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=devDB;UID=dev;PWD=dev", autocommit=True)
cursor = DBconn.cursor()

sql = """ select distinct age from user where name = (?) """
params = ('john',)
cursor.execute(sql, params)

#works fine
#sql = """ select distinct age from user where name = 'john' """
#cursor.execute(sql)

row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)

cursor.close()
DBconn.close()
```

PS: This query should only return one row and there is data is really small.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the brackets around the question mark (just using `... where name = ?` ...?

Comment: Yes I did but no luck.

Comment: `user` appears to have special meaning in PostgreSQL, at least under certain circumstances. I got it to work by using `... from "user" ...` instead of `... from user ...`.

Comment: I actually modified it like that. Its actually something like 'app.user' instead of user

Comment: That might be using the PostgreSQL "schema.tablename" form. Have you considered using `psycopg2` instead of `pyodbc`?

Comment: @FlipperPA I tried using psycopg2 but I am running into a different error where it says 'No module named _psycopg'. Trying to figure that our parallelly.

Comment: @FlipperPA so I got the importing psycopg2 to work but now I have to figure out how to setup proxy. I will let you know.

Comment: Those are parametrized, not prepared statements. I have notice it's a common mistake here.